# Why does the performance differ so greatly with seemingly the same code?

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, task-parallel-library

I have a WCF service called `TapApiService` which contains the following methods:

```
public class TapApiService : Contracts.ServiceContracts.ITapApiService
{
    private static readonly IConfigurationManagerWrapper ConfigWrapper = new ConfigurationManagerWrapper();
    private static UriManager uriManager = new UriManager(ConfigWrapper.AppSettings["tapScheme"], ConfigWrapper.AppSettings["tapHost"], ConfigWrapper);

    public JobLongForm GetJob(string jobId)
    {
        var request = uriManager.GetUriFromKey("jobResource", jobId).ToString().GetTapRequest("GET", ConfigWrapper);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JobLongForm>(request.GetResponseString());
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetAllJobIds()
    {
        return GetAllJobs().Select(job => job.Id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<JobShortForm> GetAllJobs()
    {
        var request = uriManager.GetUriFromKey("allJobsResource").ToString().GetTapRequest("GET", ConfigWrapper);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JobShortForm[]>(request.GetResponseString());
    }

    public IEnumerable<JobLongForm> GetFullJobs(IEnumerable<string> jobIds)
    {
        return jobIds.Select(GetJob);
    }
}
```

I have a Console Application I'm using to test. It has the following code:
    var proxy = new TapApiService();

```
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

stopwatch.Start();
var ids = proxy.GetAllJobIds();
proxy.GetFullJobs(ids);
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.GetElapsedTimeString());

stopwatch.Reset();

stopwatch.Start();
proxy.GetAllJobIds().AsParallel().Select(id => proxy.GetJob(id));
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.GetElapsedTimeString());
```

The results are: `00:00:00.713` and `00:00:00.104` The `AsParallel()` implementation is clearly a lot faster. However, if I move the `AsParallel()` to inside of the `GetFullJobs(IEnumerable<string> jobIds)` method like this:

```
public IEnumerable<JobLongForm> GetFullJobs(IEnumerable<string> jobIds)
{
    return jobIds.AsParallel().Select(GetJob);
}
```

I get `00:00:00.813` and `00:00:00.158`. The second implementation is still faster. I thought their performance would now be the same. What am I missing here?

Comment: How many iterations does your test perform?  If it is just one, your numbers are meaningless.  See http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one

Comment: It must be deeply inspected, but looking to code, looks like when you're using parallel at client side, it uses the same instance of the service, but when you use at service side, each iteration creates a new instance.

Comment: The two samples aren't similar. In one case you have multiple instances serving multiple client requests by performing one GET each. In the second, you have a single instance trying to make multiple GET calls. It may simply be that you are hitting the 2 HTTP connections per domain limit. Repeat the benchmark after changing this either by setting `System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` to a higher number or set [the connectionManagement  config setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tkaca2y(v=vs.110).aspx) to a high connection number